# Show contents from sharepoint list within a grid on ASPX page (ASP.NET site)

Tags: sharepoint, list, user-controls, web-parts, spgridview

Scenario : There is an ASP.NET site and the server also has sharepoint 2010 foundation. It has couple of lists. 
Within the ASP.NET site one of the ASPX page has a link. Upon clicking on this link I should read from sharepoint list and display the contents in a grid format within ASPX page.

Columns of grid will be something like ItemID, ItemImage, ItemHyperlink, ItemDescription.

Can anyone suggest any code samples or code?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use The Open Data Protocol or OData to retrieve data from your SharePoint. OData is a Web Protocol created on top of Web technologies incluiding XML,Atom,JSON. So you can retrieve the information from  your SharePoint using OData in form of Atom entries. You can take a look at the following ling from msdn blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2009/10/21/using-data-services-over-sharepoint-2010-part-1-getting-started.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the inputs. Are there any other alternatives or suggestions?

Comment: Anyone has any other suggestions. I was planning to write some webpart or usercontrol and display using SPGridview. Is it possible? Any examples? Suggest if there are any other approaches.